# How to get all checkout fields from WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I like to get all available checkout fields, including third party ones:

```
$fields = WC()->checkout()->checkout_fields;
```

returns a fatal error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_country() on a non-object in
../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php</b> on line 768
```

Is there an offical way to get them?

Edit:

My plugin needs a dropdown field with all available checkout fields on the backend. What I like to have is an array like this (I `var_dump` the `$checkout_fields` variable of the [`WC_Checkout`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L19) class) :

```
Array
(
    [billing] => Array
        (
            [billing_country] => Array
                (
                    [type] => country
                    [label] => Country
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                            [2] => update_totals_on_change
                        )

                )

            [billing_first_name] => Array
                (
                    [label] => First Name
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-first
                        )

                )

            [billing_last_name] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Last Name
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-last
                        )

                    [clear] => 1
                )

            [billing_company] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Company Name
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                        )

                )

            [billing_address_1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Address
                    [placeholder] => Street address
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                )

            [billing_address_2] => Array
                (
                    [placeholder] => Apartment, suite, unit etc. (optional)
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                    [required] => 
                )

            [billing_postcode] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Postcode / Zip
                    [placeholder] => Postcode / Zip
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                    [clear] => 1
                    [validate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => postcode
                        )

                )

            [billing_city] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Town / City
                    [placeholder] => Town / City
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                )

            [billing_state] => Array
                (
                    [type] => state
                    [label] => State / County
                    [placeholder] => State / County
                    [required] => 
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-first
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                    [validate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => state
                        )

                )

            [billing_email] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Email Address
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-first
                        )

                    [validate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => email
                        )

                )

            [billing_phone] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Phone
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-last
                        )

                    [clear] => 1
                    [validate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => phone
                        )

                )

        )

    [shipping] => Array
        (
            [shipping_country] => Array
                (
                    [type] => country
                    [label] => Country
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                            [2] => update_totals_on_change
                        )

                )

            [shipping_first_name] => Array
                (
                    [label] => First Name
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-first
                        )

                )

            [shipping_last_name] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Last Name
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-last
                        )

                    [clear] => 1
                )

            [shipping_company] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Company Name
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                        )

                )

            [shipping_address_1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Address
                    [placeholder] => Street address
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                )

            [shipping_address_2] => Array
                (
                    [placeholder] => Apartment, suite, unit etc. (optional)
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                    [required] => 
                )

            [shipping_postcode] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Postcode / Zip
                    [placeholder] => Postcode / Zip
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                    [clear] => 1
                    [validate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => postcode
                        )

                )

            [shipping_city] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Town / City
                    [placeholder] => Town / City
                    [required] => 1
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-wide
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                )

            [shipping_state] => Array
                (
                    [type] => state
                    [label] => State / County
                    [placeholder] => State / County
                    [required] => 
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-row-first
                            [1] => address-field
                        )

                    [validate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => state
                        )

                )

        )

    [account] => Array
        (
            [account_password] => Array
                (
                    [type] => password
                    [label] => Account password
                    [required] => 1
                    [placeholder] => Password
                )

        )

    [order] => Array
        (
            [order_comments] => Array
                (
                    [type] => textarea
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => notes
                        )

                    [label] => Order Notes
                    [placeholder] => Notes about your order, e.g. special notes for delivery.
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I seems like you are not showing the right part of your code, can you show us where `function get_country()` is called ?

Comment: sure: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L768

Comment: `$checkout->checkout_fields`?

Comment: What is `$checkout`? Shouldn't it be `WC()->checkout()`?

Comment: What you need to do ? maybe we can be more helpful

Comment: I need all fields from the checkout page in an assoc array

Comment: Why you dont get them in the $_POST ?

Comment: Can we have your all function and the hook used? Maybe customer variable isnt set when you are calling

Comment: I've updated my question a bit. Of course there's no customer set since I'm on the backend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i was facing the same issue . here's how i managed it .

```
class my_checkout_fields_class {
    var $countries;

function __construct() {

        $this->countries = new WC_Countries();

}


}
```

Now you can  get billing and shipping fields respectively in this class.

```
$billlingfields             = $this->countries->get_address_fields( $this->countries->get_base_country(),'billing_');

$shippingfields             = $this->countries->get_address_fields( $this->countries->get_base_country(),'shipping_');
```

regards

Comment: Thanks!, that's working for me (although no need for a custom class)

Comment: Thanks, it works in my class too, but I had to include the wc-countries class to: `include_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-countries.php');`

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party, but I was looking for an exact feature and accepted answer was not satysfying for me, so I digged into this.

As question owner said, he needs to get all available checkout fields on admin area (in his plugin).

He cant do this stright away because there is no checkout available at that point (and no customer or even WooCommerce session).

So the solution is to fake session and customer so checkout will be available in the admin area (with default user data).

```
/*
* WooCommerce does not load session class on backend, so we need to do this manually
*/
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Session' ) ) {
    include_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-session.php';
}

/*
* admin_init hook for testing purposes
*/
add_action('admin_init', function(){
    /*
    * First lets start the session. You cant use here WC_Session directly
    * because it's an abstract class. But you can use WC_Session_Handler which
    * extends WC_Session
    */
    WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler;

    /*
    * Next lets create a customer so we can access checkout fields
    * If you will check a constructor for WC_Customer class you will see
    * that if you will not provide user to create customer it will use some
    * default one. Magic.
    */
    WC()->customer = new WC_Customer;

    /*
    * Done. You can browse all chceckout fields (including custom ones)
    */
    var_dump(WC()->checkout->checkout_fields);
    die();
});
```

Comment: Definitely worthy of a +1. The only change I had to make 2 years later was to replace `WC()->checkout->checkout_fields` with `WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields()`

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but I was trying to find what worked for me and settled on this (although imperfect) solution:

The function [`WC_Countries::get_default_address_fields()`][1] does not care about the Woocommerce session or checkout and therefore ignores what is in the cart for when fields are conditionally hidden (which was the case for me).

Calling `WC()->countries->get_default_address_fields()` without any parameters got all billing fields (excluding custom ones) even when fields were hidden by a plugin. Although the second parameter `$type` can be the prefix `'billing_'` `'shipping_'`. The function returned the following in my session (swedish locale for label & placeholder):

```
Array (
    [billing_first_name] => Array (
        [label] => Förnamn
        [required] => 1
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-first
        )
        [autocomplete] => given-name
        [priority] => 10
    )
    [billing_last_name] => Array (
        [label] => Efternamn
        [required] => 1
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-last
        )
        [autocomplete] => family-name
        [priority] => 20
    )
    [billing_country] => Array (
        [type] => country
        [label] => Land/Region
        [required] => 1
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-wide
            [1] => address-field
            [2] => update_totals_on_change
        )
        [autocomplete] => country
        [priority] => 40
    )
    [billing_address_1] => Array (
        [label] => Gatuadress
        [placeholder] => Gatunamn och nummer
        [required] => 1
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-wide
            [1] => address-field
        )
        [autocomplete] => address-line1
        [priority] => 50
    )
    [billing_city] => Array (
        [label] => Ort
        [required] => 1
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-wide
            [1] => address-field
        )
        [autocomplete] => address-level2
        [priority] => 70
    )
    [billing_state] => Array (
        [type] => state
        [label] => Stat/län
        [required] => 1
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-wide
            [1] => address-field
        )
        [validate] => Array (
            [0] => state
        )
        [autocomplete] => address-level1
        [priority] => 80
        [country_field] => billing_country
        [country] => SE
    )
    [billing_postcode] => Array (
        [label] => Postnummer
        [required] => 1
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-wide
            [1] => address-field
        )
        [validate] => Array (
            [0] => postcode
        )
        [autocomplete] => postal-code
        [priority] => 90
    )
    [billing_phone] => Array (
        [label] => Telefon
        [required] => 
    )
    [billing_email] => Array (
        [label] => E-postadress
        [required] => 1
        [type] => email
        [class] => Array (
            [0] => form-row-wide
        )
        [validate] => Array (
            [0] => email
        )
        [autocomplete] => email
        [priority] => 110
    )
)
```