# Override Woocommerce billing fields from Gravity Form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to override billing and shipping default woocommerce values with input field ones from a gravity form set on each product of a store.

I can reach gravity form field values executing gform_after_submission_1 hook. My doubt is how to override billing fields.

My code logic tries to work as next:

```
//Hook action when selects payment and submits order
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "after_submission", 20, 3);
function after_submission($entry, $form, $fields){
    /*Here is where I want to call woocommerce_checkout_fields filter
     passing $entry form field input values*/
}

// Override checkout fields
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields" , "custom_override_checkout_fields", 10, 1);
//And here is where I override billing values
function custom_override_checkout_fields($entry) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = $entry['14.3'];
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution.

First of all, I need to locate the correct hook to override the order billing and shipping fields. So, I made some magic inside `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'override_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
function override_checkout_fields( $order, $data ){
    //Do your magic here
}
```

Then I've located where the Gravity Form fields are 'stored' after add to cart and finally, set the billing and shipping fields from 'captured' ones.

Code looks something like this one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'override_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
function override_checkout_fields( $order, $data ){

    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $field_name_billing = $values['_gravity_form_lead']['17.3']
    $field_name_shipping = $values['_gravity_form_lead']['17.3']
    //... rest of fields

    $order->set_billing_field_name($field_name_billing);
    $order->set_shipping_field_name($field_name_shipping);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to map gravity form fields with woocommerce checkout form fields by creating custom attribute for gravity form.

Below is just sample of the steps annd hooks you can implement to achieve the above functionality.

```
add_action( 'gform_field_standard_settings',  'gf_add_woo_field' , 10, 2 );
add_action( 'gform_editor_js','gf_editor_script' , 11, 2 );
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'set_post_content', 10, 2 );

function gf_add_woo_field( $position, $form_id ) {
$woo_fields = WC()->checkout()->checkout_fields;
```

[for retrieving fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130234/how-to-get-all-checkout-fields-from-woocommerce)

```
if ( $position == 1368 ) {?>
<li class="woo_checkout_field_type_setting field_setting">
<label for="woo_checkout_field_type" class="section_label">
<?php esc_html_e( 'Field Type', 'gravityforms' ); ?>
<?php gform_tooltip( 'form_field_type' ) ?>
 </label>
<select id="woo_checkout_field_type" onchange="if(jQuery(this).val() == '') return; jQuery('#field_settings').slideUp(function(){StartChangeWooFieldType(jQuery('#woo_checkout_field_type').val());});">
foreach ($woo_fields as key=>val){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php }
}
```

?>

```
function gf_editor_script() {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>

   jQuery(document).bind("gform_load_field_settings", 
      function(event, field, form){
         //follow the code for attribute Field Type in post custom field gravity form
  });
</script>
<?php }

function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {
  if ( ! empty( $form['fields'] ) && ! empty( $entry ) ) {
   foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
     if ( $field->type == '' ) {
       //find the attribute match and save in usermeta from entry creator email id or user id
       $field_id = $field->id;
            $value = $entry[ $field_id ];
       update($user_id,'billing_address',$value);
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

Note  : Do not paste the same code. You will have to modify some part of it as per your requirement.

You can search for an [existing](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/replacing-the-default-checkout-form-with-gravity-forms/) add-on and use it.

Follow : https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-attribute-to-gravity-forms-field/

Comment: Sorry but it's not exatcly as I need. I've a GForm set with all the fields I need. The only thing I want to do is capture this fields into ''woocommerce_checkout_fields" filter. I've made some tests and I'm sure that e.g. $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = $entry['14.3'] overrides Billing First name value on Woocommerce admin

Comment: Okay. I doubt the $entry (object parameter) you have passed on the "woocommerce_checkout_fields" filter. The solution I gave is dynamic and will work for any new or modified fields/forms. In case, you change the fields in the gravity form then $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = $entry['14.3']; won't work as it is hardcoded.